# Twisted how to get rid of Unhandled error in Deferred?

Tags: python-3.x, callback, twisted, deferred

I have a deferredList that will fire on the first callback but I'm actually playing with the nature of callback chaining and so if no callback is ever fire, errbacks will fire instead.

The problem is once I add the handlers for the errbacks, `addErrback` and a `Failure` that I created, triggers and the *stdout* still yells me the following:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: __main__.notFound: Match not found!
```

With the final errback doing the following:

```
def emptyQuery(error, name):
    errorType = error.trap(notFound)
    if errorType == notFound:
        print("[-] Item not found in given sources: {name}".format(name=name))
    print("->", errorType)
    return
```

Thus,

```
[(False, <twisted.python.failure.Failure __main__.notFound: Match not found!>)]
[-] Item not found for current sources: GIA-S12
-> <class '__main__.notFound'>
Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: __main__.notFound: Match not found!
```

How can I get rid of that "Unhandled thing"? I traped the error, I don't know why it yells me this way.

It is actually triggered with this for loop I implemented:

```
for item in items:
        name, price = item
        itemQuery_deferreds = []
        for urlObject in URLS:
            urlFire = poolsem.acquire().addCallback(initQuery, urlObject.url, name, googleClient)
            itemQuery_deferreds.append(urlFire)
        itemQuery = DeferredList(itemQuery_deferreds, fireOnOneCallback=True)
        itemQuery.addCallback(parseData)
        itemQuery.addErrback(emptyQuery, name)
```

Of course, before going to the errback handler emptyQuery I have to expect the callback the be called first:

```
def parseData(data):
    print(data)
    for code, status in data:
        if not code:
            return status
        else:
            store = status
```

ALSO, **every** Deferred that I have in all my code contains an errback handler:

```
def onError(error):
    return error
```

Note: I find this very hard to debug, if you need more info please just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `consumeErrors=True` to your `DeferredList` construction.

You're filling the `DeferredList` with Deferreds created like:

```
urlFire = poolsem.acquire().addCallback(initQuery, urlObject.url, name, googleClient)
```

If `urlFire` ever fails then the `DeferredList` observes this failure and makes it available in its own result.  If you don't pass `consumeErrors=True` then DeferredList *makes sure* `urlFire` keeps its failure result.  If you do pass `consumeErrors=True` then `DeferredList` turns any failures on its elements into `None`.

> ALSO, every Deferred that I have in all my code contains an errback handler:
>
> ```
> def onError(error):
>    return error
> ```

There is no point to this.  This `onError` errback is a no-op.  It takes an error and then propagates it.  `d` and `d.addErrback(onError)` will behave exactly the same way.  If you want to get rid of an error, you have to *not* re-raise it or return it.

What `DeferredList(consumeErrors=True)` effectively does is make `DeferredList` add an errback like:

```
def onError(reason):
    return None
```

to each Deferred.  The reason *you* don't want to do this to each `urlFire` Deferred you make is that it is the equivalent of "except: pass".  It will suppress all errors from those Deferreds.  This will prevent even `DeferredList` from doing anything with them.  `DeferredList(consumeErrors=True)` makes sure that the errors get propagated *somewhere else* so it's fine to suppress them on the individual Deferreds.

Comment: Thanks! What's the point then on having DeferredLists to yell this way? Also from twisted docs "Stopping errors at the DeferredList with this option will prevent “Unhandled error in Deferred” warnings from the Deferreds it contains without needing to add extra errbacks". "Without needing to add extra errbacks" I wasn't able to even add extra errbacks and remove this error so I'm not sure why would anyone want to have this?

Comment: Oh actually got it from the last paragraph you pointed out! Thanks again for making this clear enough!